# Filtering results by taxonomy term with Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view

Is there a way with views to create a view that shows results of nodes with certain taxonomy with a filter that lets you pick a term, shows results, then lets you filter those results again?

Example:

First page shows results. I click on 'Black' under Color, I get only nodes with Black in that result. Then, I click Chairs, to see all Black Chairs.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is, it's pretty simple - create a view of nodes then select Taxon Term (ID) then add the taxonomy to filter on & then expose it add some fields etc

if you would like a more detailed answer please just ask?

Comment: How would you get it to update the filter on every click to the next depth of terms?